# How to calculate the X-Y coordinates and Radius of Circle shape after resize of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm drawing Circles on JFrame using JComponent (AWT/SWING) and I want to make sure that when the user resizes the frame, that certain calculations are made and circles are drawn on screen dynamically (whether if it's bigger, smaller, moved to left or right etc.). I implemented the `ComponentAdapter` event and `componentResized` method however I'm struggling with coming up with something that is dynamic. Here's my code:

CircleViewer Class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CircleViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Shapes");
        final CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();

        // Class for Mouse Listener which implements the necessary interfaces
        class MousePressListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) { }
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event) { }
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) { }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) { }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
            {
                var x = event.getX();
                var y = event.getY();
                panel.moveTo(x, y);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
            {
                panel.finalMove();
            }
        }

        panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event)
            {
                panel.frameResizeCalculation(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            }
        });

        MousePressListener listener = new MousePressListener();
        panel.addMouseListener(listener);
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
    public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
}
```

CirclePanel Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Stroke;

public class CirclePanel extends JComponent
{
    private int mouseX;
    private int mouseY;
    private ArrayList<Circle> circleList;
    private final BasicStroke dashLine = new BasicStroke(1, 
            BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, 
            BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 
            0, new float[]{6}, 0);
    private Circle newCircle;
    private final Color newCircleColor = Color.RED;
    private final Color finalCircleColor = Color.BLUE;

    public CirclePanel()
    {
        this.circleList = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        this.mouseX = 0;
        this.mouseY = 0;
    }

    public void moveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;
        if (newCircle == null)
        {
            newCircle = new Circle(x,y,0);
        }
        else
        {
            int dX = newCircle.get(0) - mouseX;
            int dY = newCircle.get(1) - mouseY;
            newCircle.set(2, (int)Math.sqrt(dX*dX + dY*dY));
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void finalMove()
    {
        if (newCircle != null)
        {
            circleList.add(newCircle);
            newCircle = null;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    // Do something here and change X-Y coordinates and radius of the circles and finally call repaint() method of Graphics2D
    public void frameResizeCalculation(int width, int height)
    {
        var dX = CircleViewer.FRAME_WIDTH - width;
        var dY = CircleViewer.FRAME_HEIGHT - height;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        g.setColor(finalCircleColor);
        for (Circle circle : circleList) 
        {

            drawCircle(g, circle);
        }

        Circle c = newCircle;
        if (c != null)
        {
            g.setColor(newCircleColor);
            drawCircle(g, c);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
            g2.setStroke(dashLine);
            g2.drawLine(c.get(0), c.get(1), mouseX, mouseY);
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g, Circle c)
    {
        g.drawOval(c.get(0) - c.get(2), c.get(1) - c.get(2), c.get(2) * 2, c.get(2) * 2);
    }
}
```

and lastly, the Circle

```
public class Circle
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int get(int option)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 0:
                return this.x;
            case 1:
                return this.y;
            case 2:
                return this.radius;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void set(int option, int value)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 0: //set x
                this.x = value;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.y = value;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.radius = value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that certain calculations are made and circles are drawn on screen dynamically (whether if it's bigger, smaller, moved to left or right etc.).

Well you need to define what YOU want to happen when the frame is resized. We can't tell you what to do.

However, before you worry about that you need to restructure your classes to make it possible to have the dynamic painting.

I see the following issues with the basic code:

1. Forget about the frame size. That size is irrelevant to the custom painting that will be done in your CirclePanel. That is the size of the CirclePanel is NOT the same as the size of your frame, since the frame size includes the frame borders and title bar. Your logic should be based on the size of the panel, not the frame.
2. When doing custom painting it is also the responsibility of the component to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the preferred size of the component. Then in your code you add the panel to the frame and then invoke the `pack()` method on the frame.
3. You call your class CirclePanel, but you extend JComponent. Why? Give your class a proper name. If you want to extend JComponent then call your class CircleComponent. If you want to call your class CirclePanel, then extend JPanel. But you also need to understand the difference between extending JComponent and JPanel. All Swing components are responsible for clearing the background of the component BEFORE doing any painting. A JPanel does this for you automatically, you just invoke super.paintComponent(...) at the start. A JComponent does NOT clear the background so you must clear it by setting the color of the Graphics object and then invoke fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()) to paint the background.
4. The Circle object should contain all the information needed to paint itself. You already have the x, y, radius values. I would suggest you also need a Color property so each Circle can be a different color.
5. The Circle object should then know how to paint itself using its properties. Therefore your Circle class should have a method, lets say `draw(Graphics grapics)`. You then use the properties of the class to draw the oval. So this means the paintComponent() method would invoke the draw(...) method of the Circle class and you would remove the drawOval(...) method you currently have.
6. A "getter" method does not take parameters. If you feel other classes need to know the x, y, radius properties then create getX(), getY() and getRadiout() methods. I would suggest you don't need the get()/set() methods.

I suggest you first need to implement the above suggestions before making the painting dynamic.

Next, you don't need a ComponentListener added to the panel. Instead you need to add logic to the `paintComponent(...)` method of your CirclePanel class. The paintComponent() method will be invoked automatically every time the size of the panel changes. The basic logic would be to determine a "multiplier" to be used when painting each Circle.

So you can use the `getPreferredSize()` method to get the preferred width and you can use the `getWidth()` method of the panel to get the current size. So your multiplier would be:

```
double multiplierX = getWidth() / getPreferredSize().x;
```

Now this information needs to be passed to the Circle objects draw(...) method, so the method signature would become `draw(Graphics g, double multiplierX)`. When you invoke the `drawOval(...)` method you apply the multiplier to the "x" parameter. This should cause the Circles to shift in the horizontal direction as the frame is resized.

You would then repeat the above step for the multiplierY to have the Circles shift in a vertical direction.

You would then need to decide how you want to affect the radius?